# How to detect only the changes in the uploaded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file, crud

If i have an `xml` file (uploaded to my server), and i do some processing on it to get the data from it,then store those data in my database .

If the user makes some changes (insert,update, delete),then upload the file again to my server . Is there any way to detect the changes (insert , update , delete)to update my database according to rather than just deleting all the data and inserting them again .especially ,there is some data depends on the the existing data(referential integrity)and  if i delete all the data , the dependents will be deleted.(cascade delete)!!

## Note:

- I store the file hash , so  i know if there is some change is occurred
  since the last uploading.

Comment: What are you doing with this XML files once it is uploaded? Are you parsing it? How are you storing the data into your database? What's the structure of the XML file? What's the structure of your database? Many questions that need to be answered before your question becomes *answerable*.

Comment: yeah i parse the data and store them in the database.i use `xmlreader` to read the attributes of each element and store then in the equivalent entity in the database

Comment: An answer that reflects the level of detail in your question: Yes, there's a way to detect changes.

Comment: then please a detail answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Darin pointed out in his comment, this depends largely on the structure and content of both your XML file and your database.

In principle currently you delete a set of rows of a certain number of tables and (re-)insert another set of rows afterwards.

If you only want to update your database, you could - for each table - first identify all rows you would currently delete (i.e. do a `SELECT ... WHERE` instead of a `DELETE ... WHERE`), prepare a set of rows you would insert and compare these two sets (lets call them *DELETE* and *INSERT*):

- Rows that are *only* in the *DELETE* set have to be deleted from the database
- Rows that are *only* in the *INSERT* set have to be inserted
- Rows that are in *both* the *INSERT* and *DELETE* set have to be updated.

But as mentioned, excatly how and in what order to perform these operations depends on your specific data structures. E.g. if you have dependencies between tables (i.e. parent-child relationships), the delete operation on a parent entity has also to take care of the childs (possibly using a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause in your foreign key definition). In this case you should also process parent tables befor their child tables.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE` 
What 's the criteria to compare through between my table and the xml file .

Comment: That's up to you ;) You need to be able to identify the data you have in your XML inside your database, i.e. you have to define some kind of *primary key* for both your xml files and your database. What this primary key might be depends on your data: If you insert e.g. personal data, you might use a combination of forename and surname. Then you could do a `SELECT forename+' '+surename FROM persons` and compare this agains the same forename/surname combination from your XML file.